# tcpdf Errors when trying to create a table row with a double foreach using Heredoc

Tags: php, tcpdf, heredoc

I'm trying to dynamically add rows and columns with a Heredoc method but when I add another for each into another for each I'm getting errors:

```
Notice: Undefined index: startcolumn in C:\xampp\htdocs\vendor\tecnickcom\tcpdf\tcpdf.php on line 19537
Notice: Undefined index: startx in C:\xampp\htdocs\vendor\tecnickcom\tcpdf\tcpdf.php on line 19538
Notice: Undefined index: startpage in C:\xampp\htdocs\vendor\tecnickcom\tcpdf\tcpdf.php on line 19541
Notice: Undefined index: startpage in C:\xampp\htdocs\vendor\tecnickcom\tcpdf\tcpdf.php on line 19544
Notice: Undefined index: in C:\xampp\htdocs\vendor\tecnickcom\tcpdf\tcpdf.php on line 19544
Notice: Undefined index: startpage in C:\xampp\htdocs\vendor\tecnickcom\tcpdf\tcpdf.php on line 19545
Notice: Undefined index: in C:\xampp\htdocs\vendor\tecnickcom\tcpdf\tcpdf.php on line 19545
Notice: Undefined index: startpage in C:\xampp\htdocs\vendor\tecnickcom\tcpdf\tcpdf.php on line 19577
Notice: Undefined index: startx in C:\xampp\htdocs\vendor\tecnickcom\tcpdf\tcpdf.php on line 19797
TCPDF ERROR: Some data has already been output, can't send PDF file
```

This is the code:

```
function Table($header, $data)
{
    $this->SetFont('helvetica', 'B', 6);
    $tbl = <<<EOD
    <table border="1" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="0" nobr="true">
    <tr>
    EOD;
    foreach($header as $col) {
        $tbl.=<<<EOD
                <th>{$col}</th>
        EOD;
         }
    $tbl.=<<<EOD
    </tr>
    EOD;
    foreach ($data as $row) {
        //When adding this second row definition this causes errors
        $tbl.= <<<EOD
        <tr>
        EOD;
        foreach ($row as $col) {
        $tbl.= <<<EOD
                <td>{$col}</td>
        EOD;
        }
        $tbl.= <<<EOD
        </tr>
        EOD;
         }
    $tbl.=<<<EOD
    </table>
    EOD;
    $this->writeHTML($tbl, true, false, false, false, '');
}
```

This specific error seems to come from adding the second table row tag. Everything works when I don't have that second table row definition, and I'm sure I'm closing all my tags / formatted correctly, So for the life of me I can't figure out why it's not working as soon as I add:

```
$tbl.= <<<EOD
  <tr>
EOD;
//And the closing tr tag
```

To the inner forloop it causes me errors, I can't figure out why. *I know the function is messy, but I'm working with what I have.*

---

**EDIT AND WORKING:** After printing out some values in place of the `<tr>` tags I noticed that it's also looping through an empty value, so I've since removed that and fixed my issue.

Comment: at the beginning, remove the spaces before the closing tag EOD;

Comment: Alon, I would appreciate if you actually read my entire post before saying it's a duplicate.

Comment: @bars, I've removed the spaces by tabbing every EOD over to the left in my code and that still didn't fix the issue. Is that what you're suggesting? Just to be safe I've removed all spaces: https://ibb.co/WK8Wq8z

Comment: With spaces before the closing tag, in principle, it should not have worked. You have a problem with undefined variables. So, you need to check whether all the variables exist in the specified lines. From the presented piece of code, I do not see how it can generate the presented errors